# Configuration synchronization

Tags: views, 9, configuration

I am trying to import views from one of my Drupal 9 sites, we will call it Drupal A to another Drupal 9 site, we will call it Drupal B.

I keep getting this error:

> Error message
>
> The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons:

Configuration project.settings depends on the project extension that will not be installed after import.

I can not seem to track down where that project.settings is enabled but I did make a complete copy of the Drupal 9 A site and try to change just a field or two in a view, and import it into the original Drupal 9 site and I still get that error. Because of this finding, it leads me to think that project.settings is actually installed on both sites, but there is some other bug related to it.

Any ideas, suggestions, clarifying questions are welcomed! thank you!

Comment: Importing configuration between sites is not supported by Drupal Core, although I understand some people have been able to do so. Perhaps this is https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189229/configuration-management-is-broken-between-two-site-environments-i-have-no-idea?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install the XYZ module since it requires the A module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203367/unable-to-install-the-xyz-module-since-it-requires-the-a-module)

Comment: Sounds like site A is using contrib module X in that view. Could be a view field or filter. Site B doesn’t have contrib module X installed; thus, it would break your view, so it refuses to import.